# Regex to remove <font> tags inside HTML

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find a regex (using notepad++) that enables me to strip redundant `<font>` elements that I have on every word, to tidy it up.

I have the following code:

```
<font face="Arial" size="12">A </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">
 </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">guy </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">
 </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">went </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">
 </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">to </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">
 </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">get </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">
 </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">H </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">
 </font>
                <font face="Arial" size="12">
    <sub>2</sub>
 </font>
 <font face="Arial" size="12">0</font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">. </font>
<font face="Arial" size="12">
 </font>
```

My intended output is:

```
<font face="Arial" size="12">A guy went to get H<sub>2</sub>0.</font>
```

- The font face and size will always be the same.
- I don't want to eliminate other elements, like <sup>
- I need to get rid of newlines and tabs, but not spaces
- I don't want to eliminate the first opening and last closing

What I have so far doesn't allow me to achieve the three points above as I suspect I'm approaching the issue from the wrong direction.

**Find:** `(<font[^>]+>)(.*?)<\/font>[\s]?`
**Replace:** `$2`

Comment: Don't use regex to deal with HTML, use a parser

Comment: @Toto I think OP is just trying to edit an HTML document (i.e., strip certain tags) not actually parse HTML.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar — Regex is the wrong tool for that. A parser is the right tool.

Comment: @Toto is right, regex is for finding patterns in regular text but your problem relies on the semantics of the font tag i.e. knowing when repeated font tags are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NP++ supports `\K` and `\G` and `(?|..)` constructs (PCRE compatible),
this works for your sample text.

Note that the trimming is generalized, but you may need to modify it to
suite your needs.

Find `(?s)(?:(?!\A)\G|<font\s+face="Arial"\s+size="12">\K)(?|\s+()|(?:\s*\r?\n\s*)?(.*?)(?:\s*\r?\n\s*)?)</font>.*?<font\s+face="Arial"\s+size="12">`
Replace `$1`

Formatted

```
 (?s)
 (?:
      (?! \A )
      \G 
   |  
      <font \s+ face="Arial" \s+ size="12">
      \K 
 )
 (?|
      \s+ 
      ( )                           # (1)
   |  
      (?: \s* \r? \n \s* )?
      ( .*? )                       # (1)
      (?: \s* \r? \n \s* )?
 )
 </font>
 .*? 
 <font \s+ face="Arial" \s+ size="12">
```

Output after replace all

```
<font face="Arial" size="12">A guy went to get H <sub>2</sub>0. 
</font>
```

Tested with [RegexFormat 7](http://www.regexformat.com)